# `text-justify` not applied by Chrome -> "unknown property name"

Tags: css

I am trying to justify text in a `span`, but the `text-justify` property does not get applied and Chrome says: "Unknown property name" - see screen.

[image: Screen]

Class definition:

```
.info-menu__templates-title {
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: auto;   // other values do not work either
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check: https://caniuse.com/?search=text-justify

Comment: text-justify is not supported by a lot of browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[text-justify](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-justify) is not supported by Chrome yet.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the asterix. Is there a justify method that is supported?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more details?

Comment: Thanks, nevermind, I found a way: `&:after {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        };` It's just ridiculous. :)

Comment: Supported by FF since 2017, and still not supported by Chrome in 2023. it's getting even more ridiculous years after years.